# ¿Como puedo hacer una consulta en linq que me agrupe el resultado por fechas?

Tags: c#, mvc, linq

Estoy haciendo una wep api y necesito hacer una consulta a dos tablas de mi base de datos y las fechas me las agrupe por mes con la finalidad de insertar los datos en una gráfica.
Lo que necesito es que no me muestre meses repetidos de las transacciones, ya que varios de mis resultados tienen el mismo mes.

Este me obtiene los ingresos.

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/UserIncomes/{id}")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetIncomesUser(int id)
        {
            var result = db.Incomes.Where(u => u.Account.User.UserId == id).Select(s => new
            {
                s.Account.User.UserName,
                s.Account.AccountType.Bank.BankName,
                s.Account.AccountType.TypeName,
                s.IncomeDescription,
                s.IncomeAmount,
                s.IncomeDateTransaction
            });

            return Ok(result);
        }
```

Este es el json que retorna

```
[
    {
        "UserName": "Deyvi Roniel Tabora Paz",
        "BankName": "Ficohsa",
        "TypeName": "Tarjeta de debito",
        "IncomeDescription": "Pensión",
        "IncomeAmount": 5000,
        "IncomeDateTransaction": "2019-06-05T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Deyvi Roniel Tabora Paz",
        "BankName": "Banco Atlantida",
        "TypeName": "Tarjeta de debito",
        "IncomeDescription": "Quincena",
        "IncomeAmount": 8000,
        "IncomeDateTransaction": "2019-06-15T00:00:00"
    }
]
```

Este obtiene los egresos.

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/UserExpenses/{id}")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetExpensesUser(int id)
        {
            var result = db.Expenses.Where(u => u.Account.User.UserId == id).Select(s => new
            {
                s.Account.User.UserName,
                s.Account.AccountType.Bank.BankName,
                s.Account.AccountType.TypeName,
                s.ExpenseDescription,
                s.ExpenseAmount,
                s.ExpenseDateTransaction
            });

            return Ok(result);
        }
```

Esto es lo que me retorna

```
[
    {
        "UserName": "Deyvi Roniel Tabora Paz",
        "BankName": "Ficohsa",
        "TypeName": "Tarjeta de debito",
        "ExpenseDescription": "Dell inspiron",
        "ExpenseAmount": 20000,
        "ExpenseDateTransaction": "2019-06-10T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Deyvi Roniel Tabora Paz",
        "BankName": "Ficohsa",
        "TypeName": "Tarjeta de credito",
        "ExpenseDescription": "Iphone 8 plus",
        "ExpenseAmount": 15000,
        "ExpenseDateTransaction": "2019-06-10T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Deyvi Roniel Tabora Paz",
        "BankName": "Ficohsa",
        "TypeName": "Tarjeta de credito",
        "ExpenseDescription": "Samsung A7",
        "ExpenseAmount": 14000,
        "ExpenseDateTransaction": "2019-06-10T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Deyvi Roniel Tabora Paz",
        "BankName": "Banco Atlantida",
        "TypeName": "Tarjeta de debito",
        "ExpenseDescription": "Gasolina",
        "ExpenseAmount": 1000,
        "ExpenseDateTransaction": "2019-06-11T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Deyvi Roniel Tabora Paz",
        "BankName": "Banco Atlantida",
        "TypeName": "Tarjeta de debito",
        "ExpenseDescription": "Smart tv LG",
        "ExpenseAmount": 19000,
        "ExpenseDateTransaction": "2019-05-21T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Deyvi Roniel Tabora Paz",
        "BankName": "Banco Atlantida",
        "TypeName": "Tarjeta de credito",
        "ExpenseDescription": "Nike Air",
        "ExpenseAmount": 4000,
        "ExpenseDateTransaction": "2019-05-25T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "UserName": "Deyvi Roniel Tabora Paz",
        "BankName": "Banco Atlantida",
        "TypeName": "Tarjeta de debito",
        "ExpenseDescription": "Mensualidad",
        "ExpenseAmount": 15000,
        "ExpenseDateTransaction": "2019-05-31T00:00:00"
    }
]
```

Como puedo hacer un método get que me obtenga el resultado y me los agrupe por mes en linq?

Comment: a que llamas agrupar ?

Comment: ¿Qué debe hacerse para fechas con el mismo mes pero diferente año? ¿Y el mismo mes pero diferente día? ¿Y si el día y el año son diferentes? ¿Y si cambia la hora? ¿Y si la fecha es la misma pero el resto de datos de tu objeto son diferentes?

Comment: utiliza `.GroupBy(x => x.IncomeDateTransaction)`